# How to read cookies with Gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, cookies, jsx, gatsby

I'd like to save the selected currency to cookies and get it when I re-enter the page. There's no issue on saving part but I'm getting this flashy effect when I read it.

This is my `gatsby-browser.js` file. I'm getting cookie value and then passing it to React Context API to use in everywhere.

```
import React from 'react'

import { MainProvider } from './src/contexts/MainContext'

let currency = ''
if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
  const getCookie = document.cookie.match('(^|;)\\s*currency\\s*=\\s*([^;]+)')
  currency = getCookie.pop()
}

export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  return (
    <MainProvider currency={currency}>
      {element}
    </MainProvider>
  )
}
```

In `index.jsx` file I'm reading currency from state. But when I refresh the page first I'm seeing "usd" and then in a moment the real cookie value comes up. There's always a flashy effect. Feels like cookie-reading process is slow.

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'

import { MainContext } from './../contexts/MainContext'

const Index = () => {
  const { state } = useContext(MainContext)
  const currency = state.currency || 'usd'

  return (
    <div>{currency}</div>
  )
}

export default Index
```

Is there any way to read cookies in a faster way?